# Creating a Stacked Percentage Bar Chart in R with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have been looking for a way to be able to show the stacked bar chart responses as percentage values, according to the gender classification of the respondents.

I was successful in creating a stacked bar plot using the variable 'sex' for the fill, but I want the plot to show the proportion between this variable. I know that using (..count..)/sum(..count) and  scale_y can change the y axis so that it shows the percentages, but I can't find a way to use it for what I want. Manually doing a separate data frame with the frequency values [edit] reflecting the percentages is also possible, but I am really keen on looking for a way to use only ggplot.

[This is what the plot currently looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnEEP.png)

This is the current code:

```
workday<-ggplot(student,aes(x=Dalc2,fill=sex))
plot1<-workday+geom_bar()+facet_wrap(~romantic2)+labs(title="Workday Alcohol Consumption",y="Number of Respondents",x="Response")+ylim(0,300)
```

I know it's a pretty basic problem, but any enlightenment on this one would be greatly appreciated.

(Data set from uci.edu)

EDIT:

For those interested in the solution, r.bot (lots of thanks!) suggested using     `geom_bar(position="fill")`

Also adding this to modify the y-axis:
    `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)`

[This is what the final graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbV2a.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ggplot [online documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html) has a nice example of stacked bars to 100%. I can't adapt your code as you haven't provided the data. As an example, see

```
# http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html
require(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill = drv), position = "fill")
```

The `position = "fill"`should get you what you want.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that one after hours and hours of trying to search for an answer. Heaps of thanks, it worked like a charm!