# How to plot the ratio (percentage) of values of a variable as stacked barplots?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have data frame which consists four columns. There is column called `status` which has binary value: `0` or `1`.

After grouping the data based on `hour`, I want to have stacked barplots representing the percentage of rows with `0` and `1` in the `status` column.

In SO I found the following related questions:

[ggplot replace count with percentage in geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776200/ggplot-replace-count-with-percentage-in-geom-bar)

[Show % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)

[Create stacked barplot where each stack is scaled to sum to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100)

[Creating a Stacked Percentage Bar Chart in R with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919551/creating-a-stacked-percentage-bar-chart-in-r-with-ggplot)

[R stacked percentage bar plot with percentage of binary factor and labels (with ggplot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386005/r-stacked-percentage-bar-plot-with-percentage-of-binary-factor-and-labels-with)

and came up with this solution:

```
ggplot(df4, aes(x=hour, y=status, fill=as.factor(status)) ) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(status ~ .) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,25,1))
```

However the resulting plot does not show any barplots for `status` values of `0` (and the y axis is not in percentage).

[image]

Why the `0` are not plotted? How to solve this?

The dataframe as csv: https://pastebin.com/Y7CfwPbf

Actually, the first linked question answers my problem, but I wonder whether it is possible to achieve this without having an intermediary step where we create a new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for?

[image]

See the article "[How to plot a 'percentage plot' with ggplot2](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/percentage_plot_ggplot2_V2/)".

The code:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

df4 <- fread("https://pastebin.com/raw/Y7CfwPbf")

ggplot(df4, aes(x = hour, y = 100 * ..prop.., fill = factor(status))) +
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_grid(status ~ .) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 25, 1))
```

Comment: close, but the bars have to be stacked and sum up to 100%

Comment: I do not know how to achieve it with out intermediate `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

`perc` can be created and used on the fly, as below:

```
  ggplot(df4 %>% group_by(status, hour) %>% 
         summarise (n = n()) %>% 
         mutate(perc = round(n / sum(n),3) * 100), 
       aes(x=hour, y=perc, fill=as.factor(perc))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(status ~ .) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,25,1))
```

[image]

If you wish to maintain same colors for same `hour` bars, then:

```
ggplot(df4 %>% group_by(status, hour) %>% 
           summarise (n = n()) %>% 
           mutate(perc = round(n / sum(n),3) * 100), 
       aes(x=hour, y=perc,fill=as.factor(hour))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    facet_grid(status ~ .) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,25,1))
```

[image]